# knockout click event fires even during data change

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Knockout click event fires even during data-bind.

Below is my view

```
 <th class="cursor-pointer underline" 
data-bind="click:javascripr:SortColumn($data.ColumnID)">
```

I need click event to be fired only when i click on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoould pass the function to the click binding:

```
 <th class="cursor-pointer underline" 
data-bind="click: function() { SortColumn($data.ColumnID); }">
```

Instead of calling it via this code:

```
SortColumn($data.ColumnID)
```